# Change font size of main on barplot r

Tags: r, bar-chart, font-size

I've got this barplot in r and the title which is supplied to `main` is too long. I can change the `cex` of the `axis` and `labels` but I can't find how to change the font of `main`

```
  b <- barplot(table(FAQ[[paste0("q", i)]]),
          main=questions1[i],
          ylab="Count",
          names.arg = ynlabels,
          col="blue",
          ylim = c(0,28))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the autocomplete doesn't support it, `cex.main` exists and can be used to change the font size of the `main`